# Is it possible to schedule Push Notifications with Firebase?

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have read every piece of documentation I could find but still do not know if this is possible. Can I schedule push notifications for a specific time if I am a user?

Example:

1) I am a user and open the app

2) I allow notifications and go to a pickerView(or anything else) and set a time say at 10AM

3) Now everyday I receive a push notification only at that time

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: If the content of your notification is not changing everyday and you want to send the same notification daily at a specified time like a reminder, its better you use Local notifications instead of Firebase push notification.

Comment: If it changes you need to setup a backend and apply batch jobs for that particular time and fire them individually form the backend and give to Firebase so that Firebase sends on Device.

Comment: @kapsym How would I know when to set them up when a user decides what time they want to receive it? Is there any tutorial on this? Thanks!

Comment: Does your content change or it doesn't? for each notification for user?

Comment: The content will change. We will send something like "picture of the day".

Answer (score 2):

You can use cronjobs. Watch this video for getting started
[Timing Cloud Functions for Firebase using an HTTP Trigger and Cron - Firecasts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbE2PzvAMxA&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLkPZHe41m4jfAxUi0JjLgSM&index=7)

Comment: This video has been DEPRECATED as of April 2, 2018