# How to send custom notification in iOS using Firebase Notifications.

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-notifications, custom-notification

I am working on an iOS app in Swift and Firebase as Realtime DB. 
Its an app that sends motivational quotes to users via **Firebase Push Notifications**. Currently, I am using **Firebase Compose message** to send notifications.

Using firebase is there a way in which Users can specify what time of the day they want to be notified? 
e.g. Daily once - 12PM; Daily twice - 12PM, 8PM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to schedule Push Notifications with Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467815/is-it-possible-to-schedule-push-notifications-with-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Cloud Functions to get the user details required for sending notifications and triggered them with cronjob.

Comment: Could you add some more details to this to aid in understanding how to do it this way?  As it stands this is a low quality answer and risks getting deleted.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering